# Error: Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'? While uisng an animated bottom tab component

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using the `react-native-animated-nav-tab-bar` to create bottom navigation tab but it throws the error `Error: Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?` I have used the code on the usage section of the github repo to check but it throws the same error. Github repo: **https://github.com/torgeadelin/react-native-animated-nav-tab-bar**

Comment: happened to me a few days ago. downgrading react-navigation from 6.x to 5.x solved it for me